# Set on click event for multiple dynamic elements using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, onclick, multiple-columns

I have a dynamic form which it'll fill by running mysql query, in a better way I have a dynamic table which fills from mysql. I have put a button for each row which I want to create on click event for it to get the id of that row and be able to send user to second page to edit that row info, but I have problem with checking this multiple buttons, if it were checkbox it was easier.

this is my jquery on click event :

```
  var user_list = [];
        $('.sec_uid').each(function(i){
            user_list[i] = $(this).val();
            alert(user_list[i]);
            $(this).on('click',function () {
                var vsec_uid = $('#result_table').find('[name=sec_uid]').val();
                alert(vsec_uid);
            });
        });
```

This the dynamic part created by php and mysql:

```
while ($users_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sec_users)) {
    echo "<tr>
          <td><input id='sec_user_id' name='sec_uid[]' class='sec_uid' type='hidden' value='".$users_row['id']."'/></td>
           <td>
              <input name = 'session_order' value = '" . $users_row['name'] . " " . $users_row['lastname'] . " : " . $users_row['user_role'] . "' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id = 'Edit_sec_user' name='edit_secUser[]' class='btn btn-default'>Edit User</button>
             </td>
              <td>"; if(isset($users_row['sign_file']) && $users_row['sign_file']!=''){ echo"<a href='" . $users_row['sign_file'] . "' target='_blank'><button type='button' class='styled_button_radius' name='sign_file'>view file</button></a>";}
            echo "</td>
            </tr>";
 }
```

And this is html part :

```
 <form method='post' class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div id="result_table">
              <!--  dynamic load -->
          </div>
        </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: You are not binding to the button, but to the hidden input. You should be doing something like `$(input[name="edit_secUser"]).on('click',function () { var vsec_uid = $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.sec_uid').val()`

Comment: @Sean Thanks i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give another class name `editBtn` onto button to referencing it later :

```
while ($users_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sec_users)) {
echo "<tr>
      <td><input id='sec_user_id' name='sec_uid[]' class='sec_uid' type='hidden' value='".$users_row['id']."'/></td>
       <td>
          <input name = 'session_order' value = '" . $users_row['name'] . " " . $users_row['lastname'] . " : " . $users_row['user_role'] . "' />
        </td>
        <td>                
            <button id = 'Edit_sec_user' name='edit_secUser[]' class='btn btn-default editBtn'>Edit User</button>
            <!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------- ^ HERE -->
         </td>
          <td>"; if(isset($users_row['sign_file']) && $users_row['sign_file']!=''){ echo"<a href='" . $users_row['sign_file'] . "' target='_blank'><button type='button' class='styled_button_radius' name='sign_file'>view file</button></a>";}
        echo "</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

And the jQuery part, need to tweak a little bit :

```
// use event delegation for dynamic content
$('#result_table').on('click','.editBtn', function () {
    // get current ID($users_row['id']) for
    // particular row
    var vsec_uid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sec_uid').val();
    alert(vsec_uid);       
});
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me! But I have to use class to get the the delegate element ? can i use id instead ?

Comment: In your case, you have multiple element fetching dynamically from datasource and having the same ID name for all element. But the ID must be unique.

Comment: If you aware about this, and wanna ignore that. Then replaced this `.on('click','.editBtn',` to be like this `.on('click','[id="Edit_sec_user"]',` as latter will capture all the element with the same ID name(not recommended) meanwhile the former use class definition which more appropriate.